# Is there any possible way to create a "flying" container?

Tags: javascript, xml, controls, sapui5

I would like to create a kind of "flying" container, which can easily be placed over an IconTabBar, for example.

With this picture, I think you can best understand what I want.
[Problem shown as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdsl5.png)

**I don't want to put the buttons in an IconTabFilter!**

I would be very happy about a solution!

Yours sincerely,
Benedikt

Comment: why are those button "flying"? How do you define flying?

Comment: You could extend the IconTabBar but it would certainly not be easy. What is the use case? There might be alternatives that are closer to the [guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/)

Comment: When you're looking to the first answer, you can probably see what i mean.

Comment: Maybe it does make sense to explain a bit more "flying container/buttons". I also don't exactly know what you mean

Comment: Page has a floating footer: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Page/sample/sap.m.sample.PageFloatingFooter do you mean something like that?